# Determine if CoreApplicationView.GetCurrentView() will throw exception?

Tags: c#, uwp

Early in uwp app startup, CoreApplicationView.GetCurrentView() may throw an exception, presumably because there isn't a current view yet.

Is there a way to tell if that will happen or not, without actually calling it?

Comment: Did you got a solution to know how to handle this? or do you know how to get the current view of the window. I need it in case of multi threading when my dispatcher should point to the current view and not the Main View. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Sorry, don't remember, left that kind of programming.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but `CoreApplication.Views` returns a list of all existing views. It should be possible to do something like that:

```
public static bool HasCurrentView() {
    return CoreApplication.Views.Count > 0;
}
```

I couldn't test it cause I don't know when this exactly throws an exception.

Comment: It can still throw when there is a view; just tried it out.

Answer (score 0):

The `CoreApplicationView.GetCurrentView()` method returns the active view for the app. I think you need to add a judgement before calling it.

For example like this:

```
if (Window.Current != null)
{
     if (Window.Current.Content != null)
     {
           Window.Current.Activate();
           var view = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView();
     }
}
```